# Attach a policy to multiple iam roles

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I need to attach a policy to all iam roles. however I dont want to add the policy or invoke the policy module in each role.

Can we use for_each as below to attach policy to each role in the list?

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "test-attach" {
 for_each = toset(var.roles)
 role       = each.value
 policy_arn = "aws_iam_policy.test-attach[0].arn
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do it this way, but your syntax for `policy_arn` should not be a half-quoted string:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "test-attach" {
 for_each = toset(var.roles)

 role       = each.value
 policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.test-attach[0].arn
}
```

This assumes you have a `list(string)` of role names in `var.roles`.

Run a `terraform plan` to see if the result matches your expectation.